# ionic cordova emulate android results with failure

Tags: ionic-framework

[terminal output when running the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmHNr.png)

When I run "ionic cordova emulate android" it always results in:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'.
```

Here is my environment:

```
Gradle 3.4.1
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.3 compiled on July 19 2018
JVM:          10.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.3)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-39-generic amd64
Android Studio: 3.2.1
```

How to solve this issue? 
Thx for any help!

Answer (score 0):

switching to java-8-oracle solved the problem